# API contains JSON data how to render on HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, image

I'm trying to have a bunch of memes show up on my HTML page. I'm using this URL https://api.memegen.link/images. I'm having lots of trouble trying to display images. I cannot figure out how to use this link. The link has what looks like a bunch of JSON code and the actual website has very little documentation on how to use it.

Here's the Javascript code. The HTML is just 2 divs and an input that has an onClick that call the function

```
$(document).ready(function imagesFromJSON() {

$.getJSON("https://api.memegen.link/images", function (data) {

    var arrItems = [];      // The array to store JSON items.
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        arrItems.push(value);       // Push values in the array.
    });

    // Extract values for the table header.
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {
        for (var key in arrItems[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }


    var table = document.createElement("table");

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // Table row.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");      // Table header.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // Add JSON data to the table as rows.
    for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {
        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            if (j === 2) {      // The last JSON column has image urls.

                // Create an <img> element to show the images.
                var img = document.createElement('img');        
                img.src = arrItems[i].Image;   // The image source from JSON array.
                tabCell.appendChild(img);
            }
            else
                tabCell.innerHTML = arrItems[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    // Finally, add the newly created <table> with data to a container.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
  });
 });
```

Comment: Store the api response in state and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API in JavaScript directly to call the **memeAPI**.

For generating the `table` inside your JavaScript, you can use [**Template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which will make it easy for you to construct the tables.

```js
const getMemeBtn = document.querySelector("#get-meme");

getMemeBtn.addEventListener("click", getMeme);


function getMeme(){
  fetch("https://api.memegen.link/images")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
     
     let HTMLContent = `<table>
                         <tr>
                           <th>Meme Template</th>
                           <th>Meme Image</th>
                         </tr>
     `;
     for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       let memeImgURL = data[i].url;
       let memeName = data[i].template;
       
       HTMLContent += `
       <tr>
         <td>${memeName}</td>
         <td><img width="100" height="100" src="${memeImgURL}"></td>
         </tr>
       `;
     }
     HTMLContent += `</table>`;
     
     document.getElementById("memes").innerHTML = HTMLContent;
     
  
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="get-meme">Get Meme</button>

<br><br><br><br>

<div id="memes"></div>
```